# MacPro (mid 2012) crashing when put to sleep

Tags: mac-pro

My 3.2 quad, 8gb ram, sierra 10.12.1 is crashing when it goes to sleep. Any ideas? Does it in safe mode, after PRAM reset, and with all peripherals disconnected.

Comment: Please create a new user account (administrator). Restart and log into the new user. Try to reproduce the behavior and report back here.

Comment: This problem manifested on my early-2009 Mac Pro when the video card went bad. There were clues in the error logs. Replacing the video card solved it.